# Alternative to array in Excel for summing values in a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel table with 2 columns. Column A is a unique product name and column B is a dollar amount.  The table is contained in cells $A$2:$B$739

I can create a summary table using this formula for column I:

```
=COUNT(IF(($B$2:$B$739>$G2)*($B$2:$B$739<=$H2),1,""))
```

and this array for column J

```
=SUM(IF(($B$2:$B$739>$G2)*($B$2:$B$739<=$H2),$B$2:$B$739,0))
```

[image]

but I'm wondering if there's a simpler approach for both the counting and the summing.

Comment: The functions `COUNTIFS` and `SUMIFS` can combine a few steps in your formulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select an entire column you can use `$B:$B` instead of using `$B$2:$B$739`.

You asked for another approach, the formulas `COUNTIF` and `SUMIF` can eliminate the nesting. That way you would put `=ABS(COUNTIF(B:B; ">"&$G2)-COUNTIF(B:B; "<"&$H2))` and `=ABS(SUMIF(B:B; ">"&$G2)-SUMIF(B:B; "<"&$H2))`.

I don't know if it is simpler, but maybe you or someone else could make an optimization here, maybe using your method of multiplying or maybe there is a way to put an "AND" statement to eliminate the subtraction and the ABS.

**Edit**: you can use `COUNTIFS` and `SUMIFS` as the first comment stated. Then you would get: `=COUNTIFS(B:B; ">"&$G2; B:B; "<"&$H2)` and `=SUMIFS(B:B; ">"&$G2; B:B; "<"&$H2)`.

Comment: Thanks. Your COUNTIFS formula works fine after I replace the semi-colons with commas. (I guess you use a non-US version of Excel). But when I make the same edit on the SUMIFS formula, I get an error message saying I have too few arguments for this function: =SUMIFS(B:B, ">"&$G2, B:B, "<"&$H2)

Comment: SUMIFS needed the sum range. This works: =SUMIFS(B:B,B:B,">"&G2,B:B,"<="&H2

Answer (score -2):

Use a pivot table for your counting and summing
Click in data and from Ribbon:

Insert>PivotTable

if you want to upload your sheet, I'm happy to take a look.

Comment: Could you rephrase you answer to not be in the form of a question and clarify what you mean by "in data and from Ribbon: Insert>PivotTable". Just be a little more explicit, keeping in mind the exact click-path to get to a particular menu item will vary based on OS and Excel version.